# Present ViewController in front of UITabBarController's tabBar and hide this tabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my project I have a `UITabBarController`. And on one of it's `ViewControllers` I have button. When I click this button, a new `ViewController` is presenting modally.

The problem is, when the second VC is presenting, `tabBarController`'s `tabBar` is still visible. When I try to hide it in first `ViewController`'s action `openFiltersList()` with this method:

`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true`

it hides, but when I'm trying to unhide it, when I dismiss second VC, setting this parameter to `false`doesn't work, `tabBar` stays hidden.
Here's the code for first and second:

First (`InvitesViewController`, one of the tabBarController's View Controllers):

```
func openFiltersList() {

        var filtersView : UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("filtersViewController") as! FiltersViewController
        filtersView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext


        self.presentViewController(filtersView, animated: true) { () -> Void in

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in

                filtersView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)

            })

        }

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

    }
```

Second (`FiltersViewController`, not embedded anywhere):

```
@IBAction func dismiss(sender: AnyObject) { // close button action

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        var destinationVC : UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("invitesViewController") as! InvitesViewController
        destinationVC.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false

    }
```

I'm using storyboard for interface.

Comment: Is your modal view embed in a navigation controller?

Comment: No, I don't have any navigation controllers in my project

Comment: @TheSD i am doing the same and modal view is embedded in navigation controller. Can you guide me?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should present the new viewController from tab bar controller:

```
 self.tabBarController?.presentViewController(filtersView, animated: true) { () -> Void in

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in

            filtersView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)

        })

    }
```

Comment: Or just use `modalPresentationStyle  = .overFullScreen` instead

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 5,

```
let popupController = ViewController()
popupController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(popupController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: set popupController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

If you want to call viewwillappear when user come back to main screen.